# Подскажите по ошибкам YII2

Tags: php, yii2

```
An Error occurred while handling another error:
yii\base\InvalidRouteException: Unable to resolve the request "site/error". in Z:\domains\mysite.local\source\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php:537
Stack trace:
#0 Z:\domains\mysite.local\source\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\ErrorHandler.php(108): yii\base\Module->runAction('site/error')
#1 Z:\domains\mysite.local\source\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\ErrorHandler.php(104): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\web\NotFoundHttpException))
#2 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(yii\web\NotFoundHttpException))
#3 {main}
Previous exception:
yii\base\InvalidRouteException: Unable to resolve the request "". in Z:\domains\mysite.local\source\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php:537
Stack trace:
#0 Z:\domains\mysite.local\source\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(103): yii\base\Module->runAction('', Array)
#1 Z:\domains\mysite.local\source\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(394): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#2 Z:\domains\mysite.local\source\web\index.php(10): yii\base\Application->run()
#3 {main}

Next yii\web\NotFoundHttpException: Page not found. in Z:\domains\mysite.local\source\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php:115
Stack trace:
#0 Z:\domains\mysite.local\source\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(394): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#1 Z:\domains\mysite.local\source\web\index.php(10): yii\base\Application->run()
#2 {main}
```

Английский знаю, суть понимаю. Но куда "копать" не знаю.
Не хватает каких то действий или параметров...

Comment: Нужно больше информации: когда ошибка возникла, уже в существубщем приложении или это новый устанавливаемый фреймворк, что и где было настроено, были ли соблюдены все шаги установки.  по какому адресу url было обращение, полный ли это стэк?  ощущение что что-то не настроено, либо маршрутизация, либо конфиг криво, т.к. идет попытка обращение к ""

Comment: Приложение простое и существующее. В установке проблем нет - там всё было соблюдено верно.
Обращение по адресу http:/mysite.local/source/web/index.php

Comment: в зависимости от того что в конфигах можно предположить что адрес неверный....возможно должно быть просто source/index..... .. source - это что, контроллер?